# Java: How to decode JSON within Android? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, android, json

I've got an Android app in which I get some JSON from an API, which I now need to decode. I'm pretty far, but I'm failing at getting the contents. The JSON I'm receiving looks like this:

```
{ "messages": [
    {
    "created": "1391783287",
    "id": 1,
    "is_supporter": false,
    "text": "Behold! This is a message?"
    },
    {
    "created": "1391783287",
    "id": 3,
    "is_supporter": true,
    "text": "Behave! This is an answer!"
    }
]}
```

And I've got this code:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
```

And on the last line of the code above I get an error saying `Error: org.json.JSONException: Value {"messages":[{"id":1,"created":"1391788514","text":"How do I pay to an IBAN?","is_supporter":false},{"id":3,"created":"1391788514","text":"What is a payment pool?","is_supporter":false}]} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray`

Does anybody have any idea whats wrong here or how I can solve this?

Comment: result is a jsonobject not jsonarray...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your String is a JSON object containing a JSON array, try this :

```
JSONObject myJSON = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray jArray = myJSON.getJSONArray("messages");
```

then iterate through your JSONArray ...

```
int size = jArray.length();
for (int i=0 ; i<size ; i++){
    JSONObject itemInArray = jArray.get(i);
    // get values inside the object, for example :
    String text = itemInArray.getString("text");
}
```

Comment: Bonus : the reason why I'm storing the size of the array before performing the loop : http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#Loops

Answer (score 3):

You can use old http://www.json.org lib in your Java :

First read your json file content into String;
Then parse it into JSONObject, If there is array, then get the array;

```
JSONObject myJson = new JSONObject(myJsonString);
// get the JsonArray
JSONArray jArray = jobj.getJSONArray("messages");
//Loop through the array to get the JSONObjects
for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++) {
// use myJson as needed, for example 
int id = jArray.getJsonobject(i).getString("id");
// etc
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you are `JSONArray` is in inside the `JSONObject`

Do like this to get the data

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    try {
        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray jArray = jobj.getJSONArray("messages");
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++) {
            String created=jArray.getJsonobject(i).getString("created");
        }
}
```